# Docker: How to get docker image to GitHub

Tags: docker

I built a docker image like this:

`sudo docker image build -t docker_image_gotk3 .`

If I execute

`sudo docker images` I can see the line:

```
REPOSITORY         TAG    IMAGE        ID CREATED SIZE
docker_image_gotk3 latest c13f7fcdb11d 14 minutes ago 20.4MB
```

I searched the complete file system and I didn't find a single file named `docker_image_gotk3`. How do I actually get it?

Comment: To export an image do `docker save image-name:tag > filename.tar`

Answer (score 3):

You have to export the docker image to push GitHub.

```sh
docker save -o docker_image_gotk3.tar docker_image_gotk3
```

```sh
ls -sh docker_image_gotk3.tar
20.4M docker_image_gotk3.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Github doesn't appear to have a Docker registry service as of now.

Maybe you could try tracking your image in Docker Hub as an alternative to what Tibi02 proposes?

Just create an account at https://hub.docker.com/ if you don't have one already, and do the following:

- `docker login` in your terminal to authenticate in Docker Hub
- `docker image push your_username/docker_image_gotk3:latest` to upload your image to the registry

Then you should be able to see it at https://cloud.docker.com/repository/docker/you_username/docker_image_gotk3, and download your image with `docker image pull your_username/docker_image_gotk3:latest`

Hope this helps!